# Need help thinking of a way to code a text parser

Tags: c++, text-based

Apologies if this has been asked before, or if it is a bit too simple for this forum.
I'm new to C++ and as one of my first projects I have decided to try a textual adventure. Step 1: the text parser. 
Note that I am aware that there are libraries out there that will make this for you, but I want to code it from scratch to learn what is going on :)

So! I've gotten to the point where I add the user's input to a `vector`, so that I can handle each word individually. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out a "handler" that does not hard-code everything. 
I want to create a `map` through which to associate the `string`, for example "Go", to the relative action handler.
Something like this:

```
map<string, ActionHandler> actionMap;

actionMap["Go", GoActionHandler];
```

GoActionHandler would be a `struct` of ActionHandler type, and I would put in ActionHandler or the general messages/actions/reactions, and then in GoActionHandler I'd elaborate on the possible "Go" actions.
But, one thing at a time... The code above does not compile, as ActionHandler is not a "type". 
Considering that for now I am just focusing on having a (scalable!) program that reacts differently based on the word entered, could someone help me by showing me **real** code? I've found online people making examples in pseudocode, but I'm to big of a noob to then know how to execute what they are talking about, even though I understand the logic. 

So could anyone dumb this down and point me in the right direction? How do I include in my `main()` a way to call a `struct`/function based on the a `string` contained in a `vector`? (eg. `string` "Go" in `vector[0]`?)

Comment: I don't think asking for people to write code for you is a good use of this site. Further, text parsers are not unique to game development, questions like this should be asked on stackoverflow.com

Comment: It seems I was misunderstood. As I mentioned, I am doing this to learn, so if I wanted to just use someone else's code I could easily find it somewhere else. What I meant was that I got replies that used pseudocode and because my knowledge of C++ is limited, I would first spend a lot of time looking for types/commands that do not really exist, and then still be unable to figure out how to translate pseudocode into C++. So while I am grateful for any answer I get, I would much prefer it if examples used proper syntax/code that I can research, rather than pseudocode that mostly confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I've written it clear enough, so it could answer all your questions. (I put several keywords in the comments that you can look up if you don't understand something I did)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Interface for all handlers
class AbstractHandler {
public:
    // this as an abstract method (pure virtual) which every handler must override
    // with its own implementation
    virtual void doAction() = 0;
};

// This class will handle the word "Go", it implements the abstract handler
class GoActionHandler : public AbstractHandler {
public:
    // here we override the pure virtual method of the abstract handler,
    // and replace it with our own implementation (in this case, we print "Go!")
    virtual void doAction() {
        cout << "Go!" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    // this is the vector we'll put words in
    vector<string> words;

    // we map a string to an action handler. The value (second template argument)
    // is a pointer to an abstract handler (we need to do this to take advantage
    // of polymorphism)
    map<string, AbstractHandler*> actionMap;

    // here we map the string "Go" to the GoActionHandler
    actionMap["Go"] = new GoActionHandler;
    // ... populate with additional handlers ...

    // ... populate your vector with words ...
    words.push_back("Go");

    // iterate over words in vector, activate handler for each word
    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = words.begin(); iter != words.end(); ++iter) {
        // retrieve handler for current word from action map. We supply the map with
        // a key (word) and get in return an action handler. We don't know which one
        // is it, but we know it inherit the basic handler
        AbstractHandler* handler = actionMap[*iter];

        // this is where we leverage polymorphism
        handler->doAction();
    }

    // cleanup dynamically allocated handlers
    for (map<string, AbstractHandler*>::iterator iter = actionMap.begin(); iter != actionMap.end(); ++iter) {
        delete iter->second;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to add all those comments as well - incredibly helpful!